# Time format from list in if-else loop not working

Tags: python

Error:

> File "main.py", line 13
> print(hr1)
> ^
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

This is the code:

```
timing = ["3:00 PM", "3:10", "Monday"]

for i, timer in enumerate(timing):
   if ":" in timing[i]: # Trying to take both 3:00 PM and 3:00 from list
     if " " in timing[i]: # Trying to take 3:00 PM from list
      hr1, term = timing[i].split(":")
      min1, ender = term.split(" ")
     else: # Trying to take Monday from list
      hr2, min2 = timing[i].split(":")
   if ":" not in timing[i]:
      day = timing[i]
      
    print(hr1)
    print(min1)
    print(hr2)
    print(min2)
```

Tabs were replaced by double space. Still error exists.

Any solution?

Comment: You need to format your code. Add proper indentation.

Comment: The error message seems descriptive enough; the line `print(hr1)` is not indented to the same level as any line above it.

Comment: Use tabs instead of spaces, That way easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your first layer of `if`-statements is indented three spaces, the second five spaces, the subsequent variable assignments six spaces, and the `print` statements four spaces. Thus, the system does not know under what statement to `print`.

Are you sure that you want the `print` statements inside the `for`-loop? If you unindent them altogether, they will print after the `for`-loop is completed, solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Please Check Your Mistake....I Have Compiled Your Question & Got Outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptXxS.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in your indentation. Python is very critical about indentation.

Align your last line's `print` code to the left rather than the center:

```
print(hr1)
```

rather than

```
            print(hr1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure his `print` statements are not center-aligned, though.